# whats the difference between jQuery UI and nyroModal for creating a modal box

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, user-interface, nyromodal

I'm totally new to javascript and trying to figure out which jQuery plugin best suits my needs.

I've looked at a few and tried to implement them and basically found that UI plugin works the best but even though you can play about with the theme it doesn't look nice and plain like I want it.

NyroModal on the other hand looks right but I can't get my form to submit when it's inside a modal. I've found out that it might have something to do with using an ajax call but I haven't a foggy idea what thats all about. All I know is my form submits fine using UI but nothing at all happens which I click submit in NyroModal.

So whats the difference? Why does one allow you to submit a form but the other doesn't?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you post the code to open the form in modal mode (html and jquery code) with NyrModal? I'm using NyroModal with form for new/edit actions and works fine.